# Draw a pentagon with Postgis

Tags: postgis, polygon

I'm trying to draw a pentagon with postgis (srid 4326). My toy example works, but it looks deformed.

Here's my code

```
select ST_Rotate
         ( 
         ST_Translate
             ( st_setsrid('Point(47.601177 -3.055975)'::geometry, 4326)
             , 2.0::float, 2.0::float
             )
         , (0.0 + (360.0 / 5) * n) * 3.1415926 / 180.0
         , st_setsrid('Point(47.601177 -3.055975)'::geometry, 4326)
         )
     from generate_series(1,5) as t(n)
```

My problem :
 In a normal pentagon, the circle (which have the same center of the pentagon) should reach all the points. I don't understand what's wrong
[image: Petagon]

Comment: Doing Cartesian math on angular values rarely works well on a sphere, and is that much worse on a spheroid. What you're doing is equivalent to using a ruler and a protractor on a globe, when what you want is a compass and a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just using ST_Translate with cos and sin terms in their normal normal place. Rounding to the 15th decimal place is required due to floating point errors with the trig functions.

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(array_agg(
    ST_Translate(pt,
                 r * round(sin(t*pi()/2.5)::numeric, 15),
                 r * round(cos(t*pi()/2.5)::numeric, 15)))))
FROM generate_series(0, 5) AS t, (
  SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(47.601177, -3.055975), 4326) AS pt, 2.0 AS r
) AS d;
```

Note that the radius `r` is in degrees, e.g. 2.0 degrees in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Next short python code is not a directly Postgis solution. However, it prints a WKT format of that required Polygon for producing a layer (by using QuickWKT plugin of QGIS) which can be introduced later into Postgis database.

```
import numpy as np

diameter = 3 #degrees
polygonSides = 5

points = [ QgsPoint(-3.055975, 47.601177) ]

for i, point in enumerate(points):

    geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([[ QgsPoint(point[0] + np.sin(angle)*diameter, point[1] + np.cos(angle)*diameter)
                        for angle in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, polygonSides, endpoint = False) ]])

    print geom.exportToWkt()
```

After running the code at Python Console of QGIS I got this:

```
Polygon ((-3.05597500000000011 50.60117699999999985, -0.20280545111453963 48.52822798312484309, -1.29261924312258047 45.17412601687515661, -4.8193307568774193 45.17412601687515661, -5.90914454888546103 48.52822798312484309, -3.05597500000000011 50.60117699999999985))
```

and it was visualized at Map Canvas as:

[image]

It works well.